# Add timers in the format 00:00?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, timer, formatting

I have created two timers and they run in the format of 00:00 (Mins:Secs). I would like to add these two timers together and the resulting final timer should also be in the format of 00:00. How do I create the final timer in this way?

```
eg. Timer 1 = 02:00,
    Timer 2 = 03:30,
    Final Timer = 05:30
```

```
    public float Time_1;
    public string Time_1_format = "00:00";

    public float Time_2;
    public string Time_2_format = "00:00";


    string a_1_minutes;
    string a_1_seconds;

    string a_2_minutes;
    string a_2_seconds;

    string final_Time;
    public string Time_3_format = "00:00";



    void Update()
    {
            Time_1 += Time.deltaTime;
            a_1_minutes = Mathf.Floor(Time_1 / 60).ToString("00");
            a_1_seconds = (Time_1 % 60).ToString("00");

            Time_1_format = string.Format("{0}:{1}", a_1_minutes, a_1_seconds);

            Time_2 += Time.deltaTime;
            a_2_minutes = Mathf.Floor(Time_2 / 60).ToString("00");
            a_2_seconds = (Time_2 % 60).ToString("00");

            Time_2_format = string.Format("{0}:{1}", a_2_minutes, a_2_seconds);
    }
```

Comment: `1_minutes` is an invalid variable name

Comment: And to answer your question, just add `Time_1 + Time_2` and proceed the same to display them as MM:SS

Comment: Ah sorry i forgot to add a string before. I will change it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do it
`Time_Sum = Time_1 + Time_2;`

You can do is because  `Time_1`
 and `Time_2` are floats.

```
            public float Time_Sum;
            public string Time_Sum_format = "00:00";

            string sum_minutes;
            string sum_seconds;

            Time_Sum = Time_1 + Time_2;
            sum_minutes = Mathf.Floor(Time_Sum / 60).ToString("00");
            sum_seconds = (Time_Sum % 60).ToString("00");

            Time_Sum_format = string.Format("{0}:{1}", sum_minutes, sum_seconds);
```